# Typescript filter array of objects

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, angular-cli

I have an array of objects like so:

```
questionConfig = [{
  section: 'base',
  key: 'firstName',
  label: 'First name',
  type: 'text',
  fieldType: 'input'
  required: true,  
 },
 {
  section: 'dynamic'
  key: 'emailAddress',
  label: 'Email',
  type: 'email',    
  fieldType: 'input',
  required: true,     
},
{     
  key: 'primaryPhone',
  label: ' primary phone',
  type: 'phone',     
  fieldType: 'input'
},
{    
key: 'something',
label: 'dgfdsfgds',
options: [
  {key: 1, value: 'dsfgdsg'},
  {key: 2, value: 'dfgdsfg'},
  {key: 3, value: 'dsfgdsgds'},
  {key: 4, value: 'dsfgdgsf'}
],    
fieldType: 'dropdown'
}]
```

How can I filter this array to get the objects where section = 'base'?

If tried

```
let questionBaseSection = this.questionConfig.filter(question => question.section === 'base' )
```

And get the error: 
Property 'section' does not exist on type '{ section: string; key: string; label: string; required: boolean; minLength: number; minLengthErr...'.
  Property 'section' does not exist on type '{ key: string; label: string; type: string; fieldType: string; required: boolean; minLength: numb...'.

Comment: How is `questionConfig ` declared ?

Comment: It looks like you have an item in your array that does not have the `section` property. The second error tells this. Check this.

Comment: Only what you see above. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Kinda the whole point of TypeScript is to use types. If you're not defining types, I'd suggest you use plain ECMAScript.

Comment: It works : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20questionConfig%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%09%7B%20section%3A%20'base'%2Ckey%3A%20'firstName'%2Clabel%3A%20'First%20name'%2Ctype%3A%20'text'%2CfieldType%3A%20'input'%2Crequired%3A%20true%2C%7D%2C%0D%0A%09%7B%20section%3A%20'dynamic'%2C%20key%3A%20'emailAddress'%2C%20label%3A%20'Email'%2C%20type%3A%20'email'%2C%20fieldType%3A%20'input'%2C%20required%3A%20true%2C%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0Alet%20questionBaseSection%20%3D%20questionConfig.filter(question%20%3D%3E%20question.section%20%3D%3D%3D%20'base')

Comment: As written, there shouldn't be anything wrong with this. Error says Property doesn't exist on type, so are you adding any other objects to the array at any point?

Comment: Updated code snippet to include the other objects. I mistakenly thought that the filter would handle objects without the section property. Can the filter be updated to handle the situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error  message says "'{ section: string; key: string; label: string; required: boolean; `minLength: number; minLengthErr...`'". That means questionConfig has an object with properties `minLength` and `minLengthErr`.

So, it seems like `questionConfig` has more objects than you have shown in your code snippet and one of the object is missing the property `section`.
Verify where the objects are getting added to `questionConfig`.

Either, you can fix the object or the better way is to leverage the static type capabilities of TypeScript and define the data types for items in `questionConfig`.

Comment: Excellent explanation. My array in the real code has 2 more objects. Those objects are missing the "section" property and I mistakenly assumed that the filter could handle that situation. How can I use a filter but handle if a property may or may not be present in the object?

Answer (score 1):

```
questionConfig: any[] = [{
  section: 'base',
  key: 'firstName',
  label: 'First name',
  type: 'text',
  fieldType: 'input'
  required: true,  
}, { 
  bla: 'bla', 
  ... 
}, { 
  bla: 'bla', 
  test: 'bla', 
  ... 
}];
```

Since you have an array that seems to be able to have multiple different types of objects pushed to it, you have to cast it as an `any[]` when it's declared. You're getting that error because when you declare that array in typescript, it implicitly decides that it can only have objects in it of the types it's declared with. If you cast it as an `any[]`, that error `Property 'blabla' does not exist on type '{ ... }'` should no longer appear because the objects in the array are now of `any` type.

Answer (score 1):

@Pradeep Kumar already explained the problem above, but I wanted to add, that you might be interested in reading 
[Type-guards and differentiating types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)